# vsts Build agent access to a specific team?

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, agent

In order to not be restricted to 4h of build /month, in VSTS we have bought an hosted build agent for us Team (We can see it in Azure portal).
But how restrict the access to the other teams ?
In the Agent Queues i see nothing to do that...

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 0):

For the same team project, you can’t do it.

For different team projects, the user with Administrator role of agent pool and project collection can create new queue. So you can remove these permissions for others and delete the Hosted queue from related team project. With this way, they can’t use Hosted queue.

BTW, there isn’t the time restrict once buy a Hosted pipeline.